# How to use variable defined with "as" keyword of template in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use result  in my typescript so that i can output the length of my search pipe to parent component.

```
<span *ngFor ="let data of posts | filter : search as result >
  {{result.length}}
</span>
```

Filter pipe:

```
transform(value: any[], args?: any): any[] {

     if(!value)return null;
     if(!args)return value;
     var listofItems ;
     args = args.toLowerCase();

     listofItems = value.filter( function(item) {
        if(item.title != "undefined")
        if(item.title.toLowerCase().includes(args)  || item.body.toLowerCase().includes(args))
        { 
           return item;
        }

    });
     return listofItems;

  }
```

I have used  pipe so that it can be generic for other components as i dont want to write the filter logic in each component where i have to search through data.

Can any one suggest about this?

Comment: typescript doesnt exists in html templates !

Comment: Any workaround then?

Comment: I can not understand the question, but do you need to evaluate the result of `filter` and then use it as output of your component? Or you just want to display the length in the component? If the first one - you don't need to do this in the html. Please be more clear to get relevant answers.

Comment: @kamentk I have to output the length of the pipe  from the component to its parent component which is currently stored in result variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to filter `posts` in your component. It's a good approach to debounce user input for some period, to avoid multiple calls of search function especialy if you make api calls. So the search will be perfomed only when user interrupts typing for 300 ms.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

export class MyComponent {
    posts: Post[];
    result: Post[];

    private _searchFilter = '';
    private _searchInput$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    get searchFilter(): string {
        return this._searchFilter;
    }
    set searchFilter(value: string) {
        this._searchFilter = value;
        this._searchInput$.next(this._searchFilter);
    }

    constructor() {
        this._searchInput$.pipe(debounceTime(300))
            .subscribe((filter) => this.search(filter));
    }

    search(filter: string) {
        if(filter) {
            this.result = posts.filter(p => p.title.includes(filter));
        } else {
            this.result = posts;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchFilter">
<span *ngFor ="let data of result" >
    {{data.title}}
</span>        
Found posts: {{result.length}}
```

Comment: @Dimitriy Snitko  from where will you call the search function in template? Will it be on every input change event?

Comment: It depends on how it works. It would be better to use rxjs and debounceTime to filter user input in time scope.

Comment: @Rishabh can you upvote or accept my answer if it was usefull.

Comment: i am looking to evaluate the result from the custom pipe

Comment: @Rishabh Are you shure you need this? It's meanfull only you will reuse that pipe. In other way it will take more efforts.

Comment: yes because i want to reuse the pipe in other components as well  .